# How to make main partition larger?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I'm running Linux through VirtualBox on Windows 7. When I created the virtual hard drive I only used the default size which is 8 GB. I was able to resize the virtual hard drive to 40 GB but in Linux there's still very little space.

So I got a gparted live CD and booted the virtual machine into gparted to see if I could somehow add or resize the main partition. The extended/swap partition is in the way of the un-allocated space and the main boot partition, which is what I am wanting to add on to. So I can update or download more programs without running out of space.

Right now I am just confused on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You mean, you have a main boot partition, then a swap partition, and then a large (32GB) empty space? In that case...

Swap space can be removed and added again, without throwing away data (the only two exceptions are when the system is running and when the system is hibernated). So,

1. First remove the swap space.
2. Then make a new swap space at the end of the disk, with the same size as the previous swap space.
3. Resize the main OS partition with the now-available space (this resizing will take a long time).